# Not highlighting selected child item from navigationview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have a NavigationView & rendering Menu inside it. My Menu has 3 groups & each contains few sub-menu items. My problem is, when I select any sub-menu item & goes to specific fragment. However, when I reopen NavigationView/drawer to select another item, it doesn't show last selected item Highlighted.

Currently, it just changes color of selected sub-menu item but I want it highlighted like below snapshot.

[image]

Base Activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_app_base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_app_base"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_app_base_drawer"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Menu Items XML (activity_app_base_drawer)

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_android_title"
    android:title="Android" >
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_android_best_practices"
            android:icon="@drawable/best_practices_icon"
            android:checked="false"
            android:title="Best Practices" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_android_monthly_report"
            android:icon="@drawable/report_icon"
            android:checked="false"
            android:title="Monthly Report" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_iOS_title"
    android:title="iOS">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ios_best_practices"
            android:icon="@drawable/best_practices_icon"
            android:checked="false"
            android:title="Best Practices" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ios_monthly_report"
            android:icon="@drawable/report_icon"
            android:checked="false"
            android:title="Monthly Report" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_communicate_title"
    android:title="Other">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_terms"
            android:icon="@drawable/terms_icon"
            android:checked="false"
            android:title="Terms &amp; Conditions" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/about_icon"
            android:checked="false"
            android:title="About Us" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: group your parent menu same as child

Comment: If you want to check an item just set checkable before setting checked state. `item.setCheckable(true);
item.setChecked(true);`

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha Didn't work

Comment: @Ironman Already tried but not working

Comment: @VVB just change like this `android:checkable="true"` for all Item.

Comment: @Ironman above nothing worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is **perfect code!**

Add three atrributes in `NavigationView`

> app:itemIconTint
>       app:itemTextColor
>       app:itemBackground

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_app_base"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_app_base_drawer"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_view_icon_tint_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navigation_view_text_selector"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/ripple_navigation_selector"
 />
```

**navigation_view_icon_tint_selector**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is used when the Navigation Item is checked -->
<item android:color="#005481" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="#005481" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:color="#005481" android:state_activated="true"></item>
<!-- This is the default text color -->
<item android:color="#525252" />
```

**navigation_view_text_selector**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is used when the Navigation Item is checked -->
<item android:color="#005481" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="#005481" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:color="#005481" android:state_activated="true"></item>
<!-- This is the default text color -->
<item android:color="#525252" />
```

**ripple_navigation_selector**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="#ffdbdb" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="#ffdbdb" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="#ffdbdb" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Comment: Perfectly works. Thanks a lot. Keep up good work. Only change is need to pass @color/color_name instead of hardcoded as it gives error against drawable attribute

Comment: really  `<item android:drawable="#ffdbdbdb"` ?

Answer (score 7):

You can define the checkable behavior for individual menu items using the android:checkable attribute in the  element, or for an entire group with the **android:checkableBehavior** attribute in the  element.so put a checkableBehavior for main Menu

```
<menu>
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_android_title"
        android:title="Android" >
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_android_best_practices"
                    android:icon="@drawable/best_practices_icon"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:title="Best Practices" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_android_monthly_report"
                    android:icon="@drawable/report_icon"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:title="Monthly Report" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_iOS_title"
        android:title="iOS">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_ios_best_practices"
                    android:icon="@drawable/best_practices_icon"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:title="Best Practices" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_ios_monthly_report"
                    android:icon="@drawable/report_icon"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:title="Monthly Report" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_communicate_title"
        android:title="Other">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_terms"
                    android:icon="@drawable/terms_icon"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:title="Terms &amp; Conditions" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
                    android:icon="@drawable/about_icon"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:title="About Us" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks but nothing happened. It's same as previous